# Double click on titlebar doesn't maximize/restore windows

Tags: configuration, window-management

I used to be able to double click on the titlebar of windows and they would maximize, and return if I double clicked again once maximized.

`System` → `Preferences` →`Windows`
under the *Titlebar Action* option is on *Maximize*.

But when I double click the windows just scroll up (Shade Window).

How can I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it is set correctly in the GConf setting database (the *Windows* utility should do this, but it can happen):

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gconf-editor`
2. Navigate to *apps ➜ metacity ➜ general ➜ action_double_click_titlebar*
3. The *Value* should be `toggle_maximize`, set it to that if it isn't already.

   [image]

Comment: thanks for you help, although that didn't do it, that option appears to be already set as "toggle_maximize" yet it still scrolls upward instead of resizing the windows from Small to large or VICE Versa

Comment: Thanks!  This solved the same issue for me **AND** helped me find something I've been looking for for awhile: apps ➜ metacity ➜ general ➜ resize_with_right_button FTW!